# NAT Rule changes from ASA software 8.0 to 8.4

Tags: nat, cisco-asa

I have an Access Rule and a NAT rule that works fine with  on the Security Appliance Software Version 8.0

The rule is as follows:
[image]

[image]

However, I am having trouble making the same rule work on an ASA running on the Security Appliance Software Version 8.4.

I know that the configuration has changed, I think I am just supposed to create a network object for `ath-security` and define my access and NAT rules at the same time, but I haven't configured anything on an ASA in years and got a little over my head.

I have it setup as follows:

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

The `CORP-OUTSIDE` and `NM-OUTSIDE` are supposed to be different; these are two different ASA's. The `XXXX-OUTSIDE` is a network object for the outside IP address of each device. `CORP-OUTSIDE` is on the ASA with the 8.0 software, `NM-OUTSIDE` is on the ASA with the 8.4 software

---

**show running-config returns the following on ASA with 8.0 software:**

> static (inside,outside) tcp interface www LVMSecurity www netmask
>   255.255.255.255

**show running-config returns the following on the ASA with the 8.3 software:**

> object network AthertonSecurity-2.123  nat (inside,outside) static
>   interface service tcp www www

---

Using the ASDM Packet Trace tool, I get the following error on the 8.3 ASA:

> Info: (sp-security-failed) Slowpath security checks failed

Comment: I see `CORP-OUTSIDE` in one place and `NM-OUTSIDE` in the other.  That could be it.  You also have different services defined - in one place, it's `tcp/http` and in the other it's `tcp`, as well as using PAT in one, and not in the other.  No offense, but are you a bit over your head with this?

Comment: Basically I got put into a job where I was in charge of everything. About 3 years ago I bought some training material, books, videos, etc and learned what I needed to and configured these ASA's on the older software, I haven't done anything with them in years so its like anything - if you don't use it, you forget it.

Comment: As a first step, I'd recommend using the Packet Tracer built into the ASDM GUI to see where the communication breaks down, and if you need help after that, editing the information into your post. It would also be a lot easier to diagnose if we could see the relevant config of the devices in question (`show running-config`), rather than a few screenclips.

Comment: I fixed your edits, its not hte 8.0 and 8.4 asdm software it is the ASA OS itself, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I see.  Cisco redesigned their NAT rules in versions 8.3, so that's where I'd look for the problem.  [This document may be of some help](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa83/upgrading/migrating.html#wp83968), but not being an ASDM guy, I probably won't be of much use with just the screenshots to go on.

Comment: I did the packet tracer as you suggested, access-list passed, un-nat passed, and the result - the packet is dropped. info (sp-security-failed) slowpath security checks failed. Now that is over my head.

Comment: That's kind of a catchall code, so not of much help, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Yeah I researched it. I find it odd, I posted the show running-config for both 8.0 NAT and 8.3 NAT rules, and compared to what Cisco says new vs old should look like, I

Comment: I should be correct with the config*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, posting what I believe is the answer:

The problem was with the ACL within the Access Rules settings.
It seems in the 8.3 software the Destination Criteria, Destination: should no longer be the 'outside interface' but the Network Object destination itself.

It seems Cisco switched the configuration from being what seems backwards, to the correct way?

Comment: This is documented in Cisco's [8.3 migration document](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa83/upgrading/migrating.html#wp40036).

Comment: I know now, but I never looked at it because I thought I was configuring the network object incorrectly, not the access list rule.